# PJSIP Custom Registration Header

Tags: ios, header, registration, sip, pjsip

I am attempting to setup **SIP** communication with an internal server (using the PJSIP library), however, this server requires a custom header field with a specified header value for the `REGISTRATION` call. For example's sake we'll call this required header `MyHeader`.

From what I have found, the `pjsua_acc_add()` function will add an account and register it to the server using a config struct.

The parameter `reg_hdr_list` of the config struct has the description:

> The optional custom SIP headers to be put in the registration request.

Which sounds like exactly what I need, however doesn't seem to have any effect on the call itself.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
    pjsua_acc_config cfg;
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);

    //...Some other config stuff related to the server...

    pjsip_hdr test;
    test.name = pj_str("MyHeader");
    test.sname = pj_str("MyHdr");
    test.type = PJSIP_H_OTHER;
    test.prev = cfg.reg_hdr_list.prev;
    test.next = cfg.reg_hdr_list.next;
    cfg.reg_hdr_list = test;

    pj_status_t status;
    status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
```

From the server side, there are no extra header fields or anything. And the struct that is used to define the header (`pjsua_hdr`) has no `value` or equivalent field, so even if it did create the header, how does it set the value?

[Here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__acc__config.htm#a1e5b387485f7c7cd7dd0f9b792293acd) is the refrence for the header list definition and the [reference](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsip__hdr.htm) for the header struct.

**Edit:** I found the solution thanks to a co-worker:

```
    struct pjsip_generic_string_hdr CustomHeader;
    pj_str_t name = pj_str("MyHeader");
    pj_str_t value = pj_str("HeaderValue");
    pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2(&CustomHeader, &name, &value);

    pj_list_push_back(&cfg.reg_hdr_list, &CustomHeader);
```

This seems to work as expected.

Comment: Do you know how to add multiple fo them because am unable to add multiple of them

Comment: Since you have answered your own question, why not add it as a answer and accept it?

Comment: HI, Can you please let me know How I can pass the multiple header.

Answer (score 4):

Just quoting the OP as **he found the solution**, but forgot to add it as an answer:

> Edit: I found the solution thanks to a co-worker:
>
> ```
> struct pjsip_generic_string_hdr CustomHeader;
> pj_str_t name = pj_str("MyHeader");
> pj_str_t value = pj_str("HeaderValue");
> pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2(&CustomHeader, &name, &value);
>
> pj_list_push_back(&cfg.reg_hdr_list, &CustomHeader);
> ```
>
> This seems to work as expected.