# DMR calls using PJSIP

Tags: android, rtp, pjsip

I'm trying to make a `DMR` call using the `PJSIP` library. In order to achieve this I need access to the `RTP header extension` and set the call type to `DMR`.

My problem is that in the documentations of [PJSIP RTP calls](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__RTP.htm) `pjmedia_rtp_ext_hdr` is a structure of `pj_uint16_t` and not an array. Does anyone knows if I need to extend the `pjmedia_rtp_ext_hdr` structure or if there is another way to set the `RTP header extension`?

I've checked this questions but they are addressing the standard `RTP header`:

[PJSIP Custom Registration Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097909/pjsip-custom-registration-header)

[PjSip Add multiple headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309010/pjsip-add-multiple-headers)

[pjsip sip header configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658076/pjsip-sip-header-configuration)

Any help is be appreciated.